# Azure DevOps Pipeline : How to use a variable inside kubernetes resource manifest and pass value via pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to apply a kubectl apply via a bash@3 task in azure devops pipeline , Until now it was fine as I had a hardcoded value to be applied but I now have more complex need to have `kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml` , which has some values which are different for other env and some names too, I can't use helm chart so thats the only way I have. Any idea if azure devops would allow me to pass variables value inside kubectl manifest ?

Comment: FYI , I could see this link https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-inject-variables-in-kubernetes-manifest-with-azure-pipelines-e598755be9b , but not sure this is working? If I could get this sorted with `bash@v3` task that would be my first priority.

Comment: The correct solution is "use Helm". The incorrect but usable solution is "use token replacement" as suggested in that article.

Comment: Helm chart runs in a pipeline that can't create clusterwide resources so I have no option but to apply it via direct manifest.  Hence I need a way to pass some vars into this manifest separately , I am trying to use envsubst now.